# Go Through innerHTML to Find A Tag with Certain Class

Tags: javascript

I'm curious as to what the DRYest approach to grabbing an A tag with a certain class is if the A tag is buried within the innerHTML of an element. The innerHTML contains all sorts of divs and other A tags if that's necessary to know. Below is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
var content = something[0].innerHTML;
// I would want to see whether an A tag with say a certain class "button" exists within "content" then store that A tag in another variable.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `innerHTML` isn’t the best way to do this. Try:

```
var button = something[0].querySelector('a.button');
```

`button` will be `null` if there’s no match.

[See also the docs for `querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Full docs can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector, also if you want all the a tags with certain class you'd use `querySelectorAll` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: @R.Chappell Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'm assuming if querySelector cannot be used then whatever querySelector is doing would need to be recreated?

Comment: No. You shouldn’t need to [unless you want IE 7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).